# Should .net-core and dotnetcore tag be merged?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

These two tags refer to the same thing.

[.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-core/info)

- 639 questions tagged
- created 1 year ago by TN.

[dotnetcore](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dotnetcore/info)

- 25 questions tagged
- created 11 days ago

I propose they get merged.

Sorry If asking this on Meta is not proper way to propose this.

Comment: This is the right place to ask this.

Comment: @AdamLear And what is the next step now?