# Merge [dotnet-core] into [.net-core]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

- [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) has currently 1022 questions
- [dotnet-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnet-core) has 36 questions
- [dotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnet) is already a synonym for [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net)

I think those 36 questions tagged as [dotnet-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnet-core) should be retagged to [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) and then [dotnet-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnet-core) should be made a synonym of [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core).

Previous related completed request: [Should .net-core and dotnetcore tag be merged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329894/should-net-core-and-dotnetcore-tag-be-merged)

Comment: 36 little questions in the tag. 36 little questions in the tag. Take all down and re-tag them around. 542 little questions in another tag....

Comment: So, I think there is enough support to start retagging? Or would you prefer a mod to do the merge?

Comment: just do it by hand...

Comment: I see one or more others were going through the list. When doing work like this, please also take the time to fix any issues in the question, instead of only removing the tag and moving on. It's not like we are in a hurry to get rid of it.

Comment: Wait until 3am UTC, and it’ll be gone.

Comment: Yup, it's gone.

Comment: The dotnet-core tag has been re-created again. Can we make them synonyms now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. I've merged [dotnet-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnet-core) into [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core), and created a synonym to stop the tag being re-created.